# Determine if an account is restricted to deny interactive login

Tags: powershell

Problem: Determine accounts with password does not expire across multiple environments, excluding accounts that can not be used to sign in interactively.

I am attempting to use powershell to generate a report that will show me account's who's passwords are set to never expire, however I want to exclude service accounts (accounts that have been restricted via GPO to only logon as service, similar process described in http://paulasitblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/deny-interactive-logon-for-service.html). I have found a few ways to pull this via powershell however it requires me to generate a list of servers, and run against accounts 1 at a time to see if they are restricted. Is there any switch that can be added to this that would be able to determine if an account has interactive logon disabled?

Current script I am using:

```
$b = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$c = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires |
    where {$_.passwordNeverExpires -eq "true" } | 
    Select-Object DistinguishedName,Name,Enabled |
    Export-csv Export-csv c:\Automation\$c-pw_never_expires-$b.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```

The closest solutions I was able to find:

1. https://morgantechspace.com/2014/11/set-allow-log-on-locally-user-rights-via-powershell-cmd-csharp.html

- Issue: This requires a 3rd party .dll, and I am unsure if this can be integrated to provide a single output.

2. https://www.powershellbros.com/get-user-rights-assignment-security-policy-settings/

- This requires me to generate a server list, then run against the accounts to determine which accounts are limited.

Comment: Did you create a group and set up a deny logon on that group via GPO as described in your first link? Then just test if a user is member of that group and if so, he/she can be excluded from your output. Test the users `.MemberOf` property

Comment: So I am attempting to run this to across multiple domains, that are not linked. Basically a self audit. Which leads to the issue that the group name is not consistent (from domain to domain), so while i would be able to preform that by excluding that from a search or just exporting the group and filtering them out in an excel spread sheet. I was hoping for something that PowerShell would be able to provide me that would be able to filter out accounts that do not have interactive login. This would allow me to run in across multiple domains with less manual interaction.